# How do I rearrange this equation without *any* form of $x$ on the other side?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

It's easy to solve for $x$ in this equation: $$y=x-f(x)-1$$ where  $f(x)$ is a different function than *y*, but I need to solve for $x$ *without $f(x)$ on the other side.* How would I accomplish this? Also, does it matter the technique used to solve this what $f(x)$ is?

*If it is not possible without knowing what the function is, for my uses it is a version of $\pi(x)$, the prime counting function, only defined for composites. So, that is, what is the inverse of the function $x-f(x)-1$ where $f(x)$ is $\pi(x)$ only defined for composite numbers?*

Comment: Unless you just want $x-f(x) = y+1$, I don't think what you're asking for can be done.  There's no way to get to rid of the $f(x)$ (i.e. combine it with the other terms and simplify) without knowing explicitly what it is.

Comment: Well, if you would like to know, for my uses, it is $\pi(x)$, the prime counting function.

Comment: There's nothing you can do to get rid of that $f(x)$ with just simple algebra. Depending on what $y$ and $f$ are, you might get some useful cancellation in $y-f(x)$, but there's certainly no general method that works for all $f$.

Comment: The function $ f(x) =x - \pi (x) - 1 $ has no inverse, since $ f(2) = f(3) = 1 $.

Comment: Ah, I forgot something. I will modify the answer.

Comment: It turns out that the version of $\pi(x)$ I need is only defined for composite numbers.

Comment: $\pi (x)$ is often used for the number of primes less than $x$, which apparently is not what you mean. What is the prime-counting function here?

Comment: I mean the number of primes less than $x$, what you said I did *not* mean, but with one modification: it is only defined for composite numbers, that is, integers greater than $1$ with more than two divisors.